# Which is a common name for logographic Chinese characters in English?

Tags: word-usage

I'm wondering which is a common name for logographic Chinese characters in English-speaking countries, especially among the people who have no background in Eastern Asian languages considering that:

- The word "Hieroglyphs" appears to be more associated with ancient Egypt writings rather than with Chinese characters
- "Hanzi" or "Kanji" looks a bit specific, so I'm wondering if most of non-CJK learners can understand that
- The word "Logograms" is too generic and doesn't appears to be strongly associated with Chinese glyphs

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Chinese characters or Chinese symbols.

> Chinese characters are logograms primarily used in the writing of
>   Chinese and Japanese.
>  [Chinese characters Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_characters)
>
> Chinese character
>  n.
>   1. Any of the set of symbols used to write Chinese, each of which represents a single, usually monosyllabic word or morpheme.
>   [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Hanzi)

If I had to explain the concept to a child, I'd say "They're kind of like our alphabet", even though it's not an alphabet.

Comment: I would definitely go with Chinese Characters. When I was learning the tiny amount of Chinese I actually know my (British) teacher always referred to them as "characters" unless he was speaking Chinese. Knowing a little Chinese I can now usually distinguish Japanese and Korean from Chinese and would refer to the non-Chinese characters in those sets as "Japanese" or "Korean" characters even though I don't know either language. This is unlike Arabic, Urdu, Greek, Russan and Sanskrit which I would refer to as 'script', 'letters' or 'alphabet' since they are sound based like Latin letters.